# Difference between an internal and external link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor

I have an image which when clicked, redirects to another page. I need a way to know whether the link is internal(page of the application) or an external link. If the link is external I would want it to pop up in a new tab and if it is internal pop up in the same tab.

This is the code section.

```
<a class="lnkImage" href="@item.ImageURL" target="_blank">
  <img id="PrivateimgPreview" src="@item.ActualImage" />
</a>
```

ImageURL and Actual image are coming from the model. Basically I want this functionality.

```
if(External)
{
    <a class="lnkImage" href="@item.ImageURL" target="_blank">
      <img id="PrivateimgPreview" src="@item.ActualImage" />
    </a>
}
else if(internal)
{
    <a class="lnkImage" href="@item.ImageURL">
      <img id="PrivateimgPreview" src="@item.ActualImage" />
    </a>
}
```

I am aware that by using  Request.Url.Host I can get the host and compare it, but that would mean hard coding it and will have to be changed in different hosts. Is there a way to generically find out the domain of @item.ImageURL in the view?

UPDATE: I can do the Request.URL for both the domain of the website I am and the domain of the @item.ImageURL in the controller and set a boolean in my model, but I have 4 such sections. One link for the image, one for the image header, one for the image details and so on. So this will have me introduce 4 new model objects, set each one of them in the controller. So i want it to be possible to compare it in the view.

Comment: You basically need to compare for each image `Request.Url.Host` with `item.ImageURL`. If they are different (link is external), add attribute to the image link `target="_blank"`.

Answer (score 0):

Please review this one. 
It compares `href` with `window.location.origin` using `indexOf`. If it is found, it changes the `window.location = href`, if not it triggers `anchor.click()`

```js
var ls = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".lnkImage img"));
ls.forEach(function(l) {
  l.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var ori = window.location.origin;
    var hr = this.parentNode.href;
    if (hr.indexOf(ori) >= 0) {
      window.location = hr;
      console.log('internal');
    } else {
      this.parentNode.click();
      console.log('external');
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<!--internal-->
<a class="lnkImage" href="http://stacksnippets.net" target="_blank">
  <img id="PrivateimgPreview" src="@item.ActualImage" />
</a>

<!--external-->
<a class="lnkImage" href="http://othersite.com/test" target="_blank">
  <img id="PrivateimgPreview" src="@item.ActualImage" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is server-based. The controller, which fills the view with model, compares for each image item.ImageURL host with current Request.Url.Host. If they are different (link is external), add attribute to the image link target="_blank", if the same - it adds target="_self". See sample code below, you can easily adjust it to your needs.

```
//controller
public ActionResult Index() {
  var model = new CustomModel {
    ImageItems = GetImageItems()
  };
  //set link target for view based on image url
  foreach (var imageItem in model.ImageItems) {
    imageItem.LinkTarget = GetLinkTarget(imageItem.ImageURL);
  }
  return View(model);
}

private string GetLinkTarget(string linkUrl) {
  var url = new Uri(linkUrl);
  return url.Host == Request.Url.Host ? "_self" : "_blank";
}

//view
<div>
@{
    foreach (var imageItem in Model.ImageItems) {
        <a class="lnkImage" href="@imageItem.ImageURL" target="@imageItem.LinkTarget">
            <img id="PrivateimgPreview" src="@item.ActualImage" />
        </a>
  }
}
</div>
```